# Foreach statement in smarty php

Tags: php, laravel, smarty

I have the following:

```
    {foreach key=num item=invoice from=$invoices}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="viewinvoice.php?id={$invoice.id}">#{$invoice.invoicenum}</a></td>
        <td>{$invoice.datecreated}</td>
        <td>{$invoice.datedue}</td>
        <td data-order="{$invoice.totalnum}">{$invoice.total}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{include file="$template/includes/status-pages/status-faturas.tpl"}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            {if $invoice.rawstatus eq 'paid'}
                {foreach from=$nfseData item=items}
                    {if $items.title|substr:16:4 eq $invoice.id && in_array($items.status, ['Answered', 'Closed'])}
                            <a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/dl.php?type=a&id={$items.id}&i=0" class="btn-sm rounded p-2 btn-success has-ripple"><i class="feather mr-1 icon-download"></i> Download NFS-e</a>
                        {elseif !in_array($items.status, ['Answered', 'Closed'])}
                            <a href="#!" class="btn-sm rounded p-2 btn-secondary has-ripple disabled"><i class="feather icon-refresh-cw mr-1"></i> Em processamento</a>
                            
                        {else}
                            <a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/submitticket.php?step=2&deptid=27&subject=NFS-e%20|%20Fatura%20#xxx%20|%20Valor%20R$xxxx" class="btn-sm rounded p-2 btn-primary has-ripple"><i class="feather icon-layout mr-1"></i> Solicitar NFS-e</a>
                        {/if}
                {/foreach}
            {else}
                <strong>N/D</strong>
            {/if}
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="viewinvoice.php?id={$invoice.id}" class="btn-sm rounded p-2 btn-info has-ripple"><i class="feather mr-1 icon-eye"></i> Ver fatura</a></td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

**Return of html:**

```
<div>
    <span>No - 1030</span>
    <span>Yes - 1020</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>No - 1030</span>
    <span>No - 1020</span>
</div>
```

**I need it to return like this:**

```
<div>
    <span>Yes - 1020</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>No - 1030</span>
</div>
```

**Array for:** `$invoices`

```
Array (4)
0 => Array (13)
  id => 1020
  rawstatus => "paid"
1 => Array (13)
  id => 1030
  rawstatus => "unpaid"
```

**Array for:** `$nfseData`

```
Array (2)
0 => Array (27)
  id => 6446
  title => "NFS-e | Fatura #1020 | Valor R$59,90"
1 => Array (27)
  id => 6445
  title => "NFS-e | Fatura #1030 | Valor R$39,90"
```

The problem is that the return of `from=$nfseData` has more than one record, in which case it is duplicating the lines without following this rule: `{if $items.title|substr:16:4 eq $invoice.id}`

I need it to return only those values that are positive for this rule, that is, that have the same number.

Is there a possibility to put this rule directly in the `foreach` so that it returns only the lines that obey the rule? Or is there some other way?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected result because I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: @r_a_f It was really confusing, I don't know how best to explain it. What I need is for it to return only one result in the first `if` and only one result in the second `if`, following the initial rule. In short I need that it returns only one value in each div.

Comment: @r_a_f I updated my question.

Comment: please add sample data for `$invoices` and `$nfseData`

Comment: @JitendraYadav Ok, I updated the question, please verify.

Comment: do you want to show, like an item is present in the invoice or not. If so, there would be `2*2 = 4` results. structure might change but 4 records as you're looping on both arrays.

Comment: @JitendraYadav Hmm.. I didn't quite understand, what would be the solution for that?

Comment: just confirmation, that data is coming right but only `div` is placed wrong. Right?

Comment: @JitendraYadav Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222693/discussion-between-jitendra-yadav-and-zecaluis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over all items for each invoice. You are showing them whether they belong to that `invoice` or not. You can nest your `status` filter inside `if` which checks for `invoice id` and doesn't show them if not matches.

```
{foreach key=num item=invoice from=$invoices}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="viewinvoice.php?id={$invoice.id}">#{$invoice.invoicenum}</a></td>
        <td>{$invoice.datecreated}</td>
        <td>{$invoice.datedue}</td>
        <td data-order="{$invoice.totalnum}">{$invoice.total}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{include file="$template/includes/status-pages/status-faturas.tpl"}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            {if $invoice.rawstatus eq 'paid'}
                {foreach from=$nfseData item=items}
                    {if $items.title|substr:16:4 eq $invoice.id}
                        {if in_array($items.status, ['Answered', 'Closed'])}
                            <a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/dl.php?type=a&id={$items.id}&i=0" class="btn-sm rounded p-2 btn-success has-ripple"><i class="feather mr-1 icon-download"></i> Download NFS-e</a>
                        {elseif $items.status eq 'Open'}
                            <a href="#!" class="btn-sm rounded p-2 btn-secondary has-ripple disabled"><i class="feather icon-refresh-cw mr-1"></i> Em processamento</a>
                            
                        {else}
                            <a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/submitticket.php?step=2&deptid=27&subject=NFS-e%20|%20Fatura%20#xxx%20|%20Valor%20R$xxxx" class="btn-sm rounded p-2 btn-primary has-ripple"><i class="feather icon-layout mr-1"></i> Solicitar NFS-e</a>
                        {/if}
                    {/if}
                {/foreach}
            {else}
                <strong>N/D</strong>
            {/if}
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="viewinvoice.php?id={$invoice.id}" class="btn-sm rounded p-2 btn-info has-ripple"><i class="feather mr-1 icon-eye"></i> Ver fatura</a></td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```